# Window does not get displayed(Maximized) after Minimizing

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-ce

I have a Windows CE application which logs key strokes of the mobile device. There's a button to initialize the recording functionality, which forces the main window to minimize by calling:

```
ShowWindow (hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

Before minimizing the window, I register to the trigger button event (via a custom API). While the app is minimized I perform some button clicks and press the trigger button to end the session. When I receive the trigger button event, I call:

```
ShowWindow (hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

The problem is that the window does not get maximized. If I debug the application, I could see that the ShowWindow function is called. I could bring it to the foreground via the TaskManager by switching to the application.

Can someone please explain the cause of this and suggest any solution that I can take?

EDIT:
Solution:
Call "SetForegroundWindow" before calling ShowWindow and use SW_RESTORE instead of SW_MAXIMIZE. SW_MAXIMIZE does not work.

```
SetForegroundWindow (g_hWndMain);
ShowWindow (g_hWndMain, SW_RESTORE);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Showwindow` could fail by several reasons.

You could try:

### 1) Set foreground

`SetForegroundWindow`

For WinCE specifically refer to the following MSDN article.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940024.aspx

`SetForegroundWindow((HWND)(((ULONG) hwnd) | 0x01) );`

### 2) Bring to front

`BringWindowToTop`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504610.aspx

Comment: Thanks 9dan! SetForegroundWindow worked like a charm. I called it before calling SW_MAXIMIZE and now the window gets displayed without a problem. The second method does not seem to work though. Once again, Thank  you

Answer (score 3):

Second parameter in `ShowWindow(HWND hWnd, int nCmdShow)` can take a value:

```
SW_HIDE, SW_SHOW, SW_SHOWNA, SW_SHOWNORMAL
```

The last one activates and displays window; it will be restored to its original size and position.

About windows functions in WinCE you can read on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502238.aspx).

Comment: SHOWNORMAL doesn't seem to work either. My problem seems to be a bit more complicated than simply minimizing and restoring an app. Might be because I open/close other applications while the monitoring app is minimized. I've tried combinations of ShowWindow, MoveWindow and SetWindowPos but none of them seems to work.

Comment: SW_SHOWNORMAL will restore window; if it was maximized, it should be restored to that state, but it will not be maximized using this parameter. I wanted to say you should pay attention to those parameters, SW_MAXIMIZE is not supposed to be used with this function (we speak about Win CE), you can read it following link I posted above. I'm not sure if there is a way to maximize window (I'm not a Win CE programmer), but the tricky solution can be using SetWindowPos or MoveWindow to lay out window. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try to first restore window, then maximize.

I don't have Windows CE so can't test, but that should work.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Thanks Alf. I tried putting SW_RESTORE before maximize but it still doesn't work.